# How to get a Sleep button on the Log-In screen?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, login-screen

Quite often my cat wakes up my PC after I've put it to Sleep.

It would be extremely useful to be able to put the computer back to Sleep without the need to Log back into the system again (password on wake is required) but I can't find any way of getting a Sleep button on my Log In screen.

I'm using 64-bit Windows 7 Professional.

Is this possible to add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there's no specific *sleep* button, you can just click the little arrow next to the shutdown button to get additional options:

[image: Shutdown options]

If the shutdown button is missing from the log on screen, open `regedit.exe`, and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`. Then make sure the `ShutdownWithoutLogon` value is set to `1`.

---

For Professional, Ultimate or Enterprise editions only:

1. Click on Start, type `gpedit.msc` in the search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. In Local Group Policy Editor navigate to **User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar**.
3. Double-click on **Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands**.
4. Make sure the setting is either set to **Not configured** or **Disabled**.
5. Apply the changes and press OK.

> This policy setting prevents users from performing the following commands from the Start menu or Windows Security screen: Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate. This policy setting does not prevent users from running Windows-based programs that perform these functions.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, the Power button and the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands are removed from the Start menu. The Power button is also removed from the Windows Security screen, which appears when you press CTRL+ALT+DELETE.
>
> If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, the Power button and the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands are available on the Start menu. The Power button on the Windows Security screen is also available.
>
> <sub>Source: [Group Policy Search](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#4635)</sub>

Comment: I don't currently have any button like that on the Log-In screen. However, the registry key you list already is set to 1

Comment: Following on from this, I set the value to 0, rebooted, set the value back to 1, rebooted, and this time  the button is now back on my Log In screen. It would appear that the registry value itself can sometimes not latch into the software that uses it and it needs telling again! Anyone, button back now, I'm happy! Thanks

Comment: Bizarrely, after another reboot the button has disappeared again. Not sure what is doing this but really annoying.

Comment: @Dave I've updated the post with additional info.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it was already "not configured". I have the options in the start menu, and I can get them to appear on the login screen once, but after a reboot it disappears. Something is removing it, just can't work out what it could be.

Comment: @Dave Is the computer within a domain? Try setting it to **Disabled** and see whether it makes any difference.

Comment: Disabled didn't help either. And no, not a domain. This is a home PC, Admin account with UAC disabled.

Comment: @Dave Yes, like I guessed; just making sure. Try performing a [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us), and see whether it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem of the missing shut down button in the login screen. I found that pressing the switch user button under the password box makes the shutdown/sleep button appear in the bottom right hand corner of the screen.